# Why is it so complex to convert a video file into FLV?

Tags: video, video-streaming, flv, video-encoding

I'm reading more on the topic, includig Qs on SO and everyone seems to have used some bit of hackery so as to get a certain video-type encoded into FLV. Why is it such a big deal? Seems very simple to convert one format into another, but that doesnt appear to be the case...

Comment: After all, video is so simple.  It's just numbers.

Comment: Of course. Do you have any insights on the topic?

Comment: Where is the question here?  What is a big deal - you have an API, then you use it, and then you have your file.

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg works for me.